# rails ArgumentError: You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am getting this error message:

```
    ArgumentError: You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
  Instead of: match "controller#action"
  Do: get "controller#action"
```

Here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

  root 'static_pages#home'
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  get  '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/subscribe', to: 'static_pages#subscribe'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get 'sessions/new', to: 'sessions#new'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy' , via: :delete
  get '/resend', to: 'users#resend'
  post '/resend_activation', to: 'users#resend_activation'

end
```

I will appreciate any help in locating what i have done wrong with my routing and how best to solve the problem.

Comment: Is this really the correct routesfile?

Comment: Does the error persist if you remove  the `mount railsadmin` call?

Comment: It makes no difference when i remove the line: mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'